# Resizing cell in GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

Like the title suggests, I want to resize grid components so that if there is a small component inside of a grid it will remove excess space.

Here's an example of what it currently looks like:

[image: What it currently looks like.]

Instead it should look like this:

[image: This.]

I'm using a `GridLayout`. Which looks kinda like:

```
grid = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 3));
grid.add(JPanel1);
grid.add(Jpanel2);
grid.add(JTextField);`
```

Any ideas?

*EDIT*: I fixed the problem by using a MigLayout(Thanks @Blip) and overriding the preferred size. Blip then told me not to override, rather use the MigLayout's additional functionality to get the same results. While that would work, I also decided to change the height of the JTextField. Otherwise I would use the other solution. But thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: why don't you use a different layout manager?

Comment: @Blip all the other ones shrink the JTextField to 1 px wide. Unless you know of one that doesn't. I've tried other ones with `setMinimumSize()` but that doesn't do anything.

Comment: have you tried **MigLayout**?

Comment: Use GridBagLayout. With its combination of fill and weight parameters for a component specified by the constraints you give it, you should get what you're looking for.

Comment: Use an appropriate constructor to establish the desired initial size of text components, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26524195/230513).

Comment: @Blip MigLayout works great, but now the JTextField isn't showing up. Do you know what the problem could be?

Comment: could you post the code you used?

Comment: @Blip `grid = new JPanel(new MigLayout());
grid.add(JLabel1);
grid.add(JLabel2);
grid.add(JTextField1);`

Comment: it would be `grid = new JPanel(new MigLayout("fill", "[][][grow]", "[]"));` and it should work correctly.

Comment: @blip Fixed it by overriding the `getPreferredSize()` function. It's working now, thanks!

Comment: if you used the code in my previous post you would not require to override the `getPreferredSize` method.

Comment: `GridBagLayout` would be a preferred choice here because accomplishing this is very easy. The problem with external libraries is that you require others to have them or you will need to bundle them.

Comment: @user1803551 How is this not the case with libGDX or other libraries like that?

Comment: It is the same case.

Answer (score 1):

> all the other ones shrink the JTextField to 1 px wide.

No they don't. First of all make sure you create the text field with code like:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
```

The number will all the text field to determine a reasonable preferred size.

You could then use a `FlowLayout`, which always respects the preferred size.

Or you could use a `GridBagLayout` which is more flexible, but also more complicated to use. Yes, when you use a GridBagLayout, if you shrink the fame too small, then components will be displayed at their minimum size, which could be a few pixels for a text field.

The key is to use frame.pack() so components are displayed at their preferred size so you don't have to worry about components shrinking.

Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information.